# How to apply css classes to the TimeDurationWidget in Django

Tags: django, widget, modelform

I am trying to apply css styling to my modelform.

```
from durationwidget.widgets import TimeDurationWidget

class WeightDistanceTimeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    weight = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Weight', 'class': 'form-control', 'step': 2.5}))
    distance = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Distance', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    time = forms.DurationField(widget=TimeDurationWidget(show_days=False, show_hours=True, show_minutes=True, show_seconds=True), required=False)
```

My weight and distance fields are showing up how I'd like but does anyone know how I can apply a placeholder and class of `form-control` to each of `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`. I can't seem to find any documentation that explains this anywhere. Alternatively, is there a better way to display this information?

I have also tried adding the class directly into my template:

```
<div class="form-control">
    {{ form.time }}
</div>
```

But this didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply custom attributes to the `TimeDurationWidget` in the same way you've already applied them to the `NumberInputWidget`:

```
time = forms.DurationField(widget=TimeDurationWidget(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, show_days=False, show_hours=True, show_minutes=True, show_seconds=True), required=False)
```

You can even hardcode some quick and dirty CSS in there (not recommended):

```
time = forms.DurationField(widget=TimeDurationWidget(attrs={'style': 'border: 10px dotted red'}, show_days=False, show_hours=True, show_minutes=True, show_seconds=True), required=False)
```

This is all documented in [Django's Widget documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances):

> On a real Web page, you probably don’t want every widget to look the same. You might want a larger input element for the comment, and you might want the ‘name’ widget to have some special CSS class. It is also possible to specify the ‘type’ attribute to take advantage of the new HTML5 input types. To do this, you use the Widget.attrs argument when creating the widget: